# How to cache/save image api results for each user and then cycle through it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, google-api, bing-api

I'm having an issue with a functionality. The idea is to allow users to enter two search terms. Have rails query an image api like google or bing, returning the image results. The results are then cycled through, showing random images of the search, side by side.

My working version followed this logic:

```
Controller
  def new
    Array1 = ImageSearch("dogs")
    Array2 = ImageSearch("cats")

    @left_image = Array1.sample
    @right_image = Array2.sample
  end
end
```

I understand this is bad because it makes new calls to the api each time new is accessed.
How do I make it so that data recieved from the api persists and can be manipulated after recieving it?

My initial two ideas were to store the results in a DB (but this seems inefficient), or send the JSON results to the browser and have it cycle through the images.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recieving the data from Bing and resending it to the browser with JSON. The browser is then able to cycle through the photos with jquery.